# every push, do X for git

Tags: git

I want to set up a system so that for every push to a PR, it spins up a server. How can I set up GIT so that it communicates to a third party app whenever someone pushes to a PR? I need to know the PR number to associate the PR with a server. How can I get that information?

Comment: You can use git hook. Look in `.git/hooks` for examples. BTW you push to a repo not to a PR.

Comment: You'll need to setup a webhook if you're you talking about [tag:github] pull requests specifically, because they don't allow regular git hooks server-side. Although, their api is quite robust.